# Replacing delegate with on event

Tags: jquery

I have a grid of users, and I can add a new user to that grid.
Because that is what I am doing, when I pick up the remove row event I have to use a jquery delegate to attach the event to the context rather than the page.
Today we should be replacing `delegate` with `on`.
Yet of the 2 functions below, only the delegate version captures the click event of the remove button. Why is this?

// Does not work

```
$(".removeRow").on("click", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $row = $this.closest("tr");
    var username = $row.data("msurvey-username");
    var url = GetHiddenField("msurvey-remove-employee");
    dataService.removeEmployee(username, $row, removeEmployeeFromGrid, url);
});
```

// Does not work

```
$("body").on(".removeRow", "click", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $row = $this.closest("tr");
    var username = $row.data("msurvey-username");
    var url = GetHiddenField("msurvey-remove-employee");
    dataService.removeEmployee(username, $row, removeEmployeeFromGrid, url);
});
```

// This does work

```
$("body").delegate(".removeRow", "click", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $row = $this.closest("tr");
    var username = $row.data("msurvey-username");
    var url = GetHiddenField("msurvey-remove-employee");
    dataService.removeEmployee(username, $row, removeEmployeeFromGrid, url);
});
```

Comment: check this link http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(parentSelector).on('click', 'elementSelector', function() {
    // Handler Code here
});
```

Where `parentSelector` is common and static parent of `elementSelector`. This will be faster as compared to `document` as parentSelector.

Comment: All the answers are correct and upticked. But it is good to get that extra information that your answer gives.

Answer (score 5):

For [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) with `.on()` use this:

```
$(document).on("click", '.removeRow',function () {
    //Your code ...
});
```

Notes:

1. Try to avoid using `body` for the binding as there might occur a bug
2. It's recommended to use the nearest static parent instead of the `document`

Answer (score 5):

Correct Syntax for [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach is.

i.e.

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

So change your event binding call to

```
$(document).on("click", ".removeRow", function () {
    //Your code
});
```

For better performance you should use closest static container instead of `document`.